# How is inter-area routing carried out in OSPF?

Tags: routing, router, ospf, protocol-theory

If all the areas learn routes to the other areas through Area 0, does it mean that two non-backbone areas cannot communicate with each other? What does ABR do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Non-Area 0 areas cannot directly communicate; all inter-area traffic is through Area 0. An ABR is a router with one foot in in Area 0, and another foot in a different area.

The one exception where you may have two non-Area 0 areas connected to each other involves a virtual link, but even then, the area not touching Area 0 must communicate using the virtual link to Area 0. This is not a recommended solution since traffic will not be direct between the two non-Area 0 areas, but it is available if there are no other options. It may also be used if you have a disconnected Area 0 to join the disconnected part of Area 0, but, again, this is not a recommended solution.

Comment: There is the possibility of having traffic between areas not traversing area 0 but I would consider it a corner case. It involves virtual links and the capability transit. There's a good post at the INE blog about it. http://blog.ine.com/2009/09/14/understanding-ospf-transit-capability/